# Assigning values from dictionary into a struct

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a struct given like so....

```
struct CricketerDetail {
  var image: UIImage!
  var name: String!
  var details: String!

  init(image: UIImage, name: String, details: String) {
    self.image = image
    self.name = name
    self.details = details
  }
}
```

Now I have a function given like so...

[image]

In the screenshot, `Common2` is given as,

```
class Common2: NSObject {

  class func generateCricketerDetailList() -> [[String:Any]] {
    return [["name": "Sachin Tendulkar","description":"add descr. here","image": UIImage(named: "Sachin.jpeg")!],["name":"Sourav Ganguly","description":"add descr. here","image":UIImage(named: "sourav.jpeg")!],["name":"Adam Gilchrist","description":"add descr. here","image":UIImage(named: "adam.jpeg")!],["name":"Jonty Rhodes","description":"add descr. here","image":UIImage(named: "adam.jpeg")!],["name":"Wasim Akram","description":"add descr. here","image":UIImage(named: "wasim.jpg")!]]
  }
}
```

Now how do I specifically add the image, name and details of this dictionary into the array `cricketerDetailList` as given in the screenshot..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the value associated with the `description` key to be the value for the property `details` in your `CricketerDetail` struct.

You should simply access the dictionary using the keys and cast them to the appropriate types:

```
cricketerDetailList.append(
    CricketerDetail(image: item["image"] as! UIImage,
                    name: item["name"] as! String,
                    details: item["description"] as! String))
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **never ever** declare properties or struct members as implicit unwrapped optionals which are initialized with non-optional values in an `init` method.

Remove the exclamation marks.

```
struct CricketerDetail {
  var image: UIImage
  var name: String
  var details: String

...
```

The most efficient way to map one type to another is to use `map`

```
func getAllCricketerDetailList() -> [CricketerDetail] {
    return Common2.generateCricketerDetailList().map { item -> CricketerDetail in
         CricketerDetail(image: item["image"] as! UIImage, name: item["name"] as! String, details: item["description"] as! String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @vadian...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
let allCricketerDetailList = generateCricketerDetailList()
//inside for loop
let detail = CricketerDetail(name: allCricketerDetailList["name"] as! String.........)
```

But my suggest would be initializing struct with dicitonary.
e.g.

```
 struct CricketerDetail {
  var image: UIImage!
  var name: String!
  var details: String!

  init(dict: [String:Any]) {
    self.image = dict["image"] as? UIImage ?? UIImage()
    self.name = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
    self.details = dict["description"] as? String ?? ""
  }
}
```

After you set your struct like this, you will init your struct like below:

```
//for loop
cricketerDetailList.append(CricketerDetail(dict: item) //item is coming from your loop
```